# How to Select Nullable Value from a coloumn in the List

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-dataset

How can I select the Nullable Value from a column from the list.

Say for example I have a dataset converted into a list like below instead of passing a value in the client id(nullable column). I need to pass null. I've made the following attempts myself:

```
var reqlist = (from list in tableList.AsEnumerable()
                where (list.Field<int?>("ClientID") == clientID)
                       && list.Field<bool>("VisibleToAdmin") == true
                       && list.Field<bool>("Required") == true
                select list.Field<string>("FieldName"));
```

1.

```
var reqlist = (from list in tableList.AsEnumerable()
                 where (list.Field<int?>("ClientID") == null)
                        && list.Field<bool>("VisibleToAdmin") == true
                        && list.Field<bool>("Required") == true
                 select list.Field<string>("FieldName"));
```

2.

```
var reqlist = (from list in tableList.AsEnumerable()
                 where (list.Field<int?>("ClientID") == (int?)(null))
                        && list.Field<bool>("VisibleToAdmin") == true
                        && list.Field<bool>("Required") == true
                 select list.Field<string>("FieldName"));
```

3.

```
var reqlist = (from list in tableList.AsEnumerable()
                 where (list.Field<int?>("ClientID") == (bool?)(null))
                        && list.Field<bool>("VisibleToAdmin") == true
                        && list.Field<bool>("Required") == true
                 select list.Field<string>("FieldName"));
```

4.

```
var reqlist = (from list in tableList.AsEnumerable()
                 where (list.IsNull("ClientID"))
                        && list.Field<bool>("VisibleToAdmin") == true
                        && list.Field<bool>("Required") == true
                 select list.Field<string>("FieldName"));
```

With all of the above methods, an `InvalidCastException` is thrown.

Comment: Step 1: Spell-check your question before posting. Or after.

Comment: @DACrosby: +1 for your edit. Does wonders for legibility. (@mohamed: hint, hint ;)

Comment: Are you sure that you are using the correct types for the fields in your `Field<T>` calls? It occurs to me that getting this wrong may throw this kind of exception as well...

Answer (score 0):

It's completely legal to compare nullable value with null:

```
list.Field<int?>("ClientID") == null
// same as 
!list.Field<int?>("ClientID").HasValue
```

Looks like you have `DbNull.Value` in either *VisibleToAdmin* or *Required* field. So, you should use nullable bool to get those fields values:

```
int? clientID = null;
var reqlist = from r in tableList.AsEnumerable()
              where r.Field<int?>("ClientID") == clientID &&
                    r.Field<bool?>("VisibleToAdmin") == true &&
                    r.Field<bool?>("Required") == true
              select r.Field<string>("FieldName");
```

Comment: Thanks lazyberezovsky.It is Working Well.

Comment: @mohamedKalithu that's good. Please mark answer as accepted for others to see that problem was solved